# pass attributes between java web server and php web server by redirecting

Tags: java, php, web-applications, web

scenario:user visits web container A(Apache Tomcat), A set values in session scope,

```
HttpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute(“key”, “value”);
```

and redirect user to another web container B(a php server).

```
HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("path to server B");
```

Could B get the same values in session scope which's set by A?

```
HttpServletRequest.getSession().getAttribute(“key”);
```

according to this question, [java servlet application scope redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744528)

it seems possible, though it might be **redirecting to the same container**,
the httpsession would be **in the same VM**, 
or **another container in the load-balancing server**, 
httpsession could **migrate between these container**, 
thus ***httpsession*** would ***stay still*** in these two cases.

what if I want to pass attributes between two different server(java and PHP) while redirecting?

wish I do express my thoughts right, any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to pass attributes between a Java web server and a PHP web server, you have to add them to the outgoing HTTP request as request parameters (as part of query string, the portion of the HTTP URL after `?`).

The `HttpSession` information in a Java web server is available on the server side and is connected between two stateless HTTP sessions through `JSESSIONID` request parameter or cookie (based on if the browser supports cookies). So, any attributes set in the Session of a Java web server will not be available to the PHP web server.

Comment: on a second thought, is there any reference I could refer to..?